# Visual Studio - Debugger Breakpoints Move and no longer hit the lines they are supposed to

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Currently I'm seeing an oddity in functions in one of my programs in visual studio is acting. VS allows me to put break points at certain points in the file, but then in debug mode it moves these break points to spaces and comments.

Things I've already tried:

1. Deleted the PDB file and rebuilt.
2. Deleted the EXE file and rebuilt.
3. Rebuilt the whole project. (Clean, Rebuild)
4. Checked that Optimization is off.
5. Checked that the debug path is the same as the build output path.
6. "Require source files to exactly match the original version" flag is checked.

In case there is simply something odd with my code causing this here is the function it happens in:

```
bool BManager::Record(string _strFile)
{
   bool bSuccess = false;
   CBitmap * bitmap = new CBitmap();
   HBITMAP  handle = NULL;
   HPALETTE hPalette = NULL;
   //LoadBitmapFromBMPFile( (LPTSTR)_strFile.c_str(), &handle, &hPalette);
   ofstream out;
   out.open(_strFile.c_str());

   handle = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, (LPTSTR)_strFile.c_str(), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE);

   bitmap->FromHandle(handle);
   bSuccess = ImageBitmap_Record(bitmap);
   delete bitmap;
   bitmap = NULL;
   CloseHandle(handle);
   return bSuccess;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: +1 this happens to me too, and I haven't figured it out yet

Comment: I see it but only when it's caused by one of the things on your list. Maybe something strange going on with end-of-lines or something else that might be confusing the text editor's line count vs the debugger's? Or maybe the wrong debug symbols are being loaded (sometimes VS load other PDB versions from a stupid place no matter how hard you tell it; check with Process Explorer which .PDB file it is really loading, perhaps).

Comment: Tools + Options, Debugging, General, "Require source files to exactly match the original version".  Ensure that's ticked.

Comment: Yes, that option is checked Hans. I've added it to the list of things already tried.

Comment: Leo do you have a link as to how I would do that?

Comment: @Leo Davidson: We encountered this problem on one system only. The CPP file where this happened was actually mixed line endings, and the developer to get this problem manually edited the file in GVIM, and then it happened... So many thanks, your end-of-line hint was very helpful, just normalizing line-endings in Visual Studio fixed it :)

Comment: Just had the same thing. Line endings looked to be the cause. To re-normalized endings in Visual Studio for those that don't know, open the file, go to File ->Advanced Save Options and changing Line endings to Windows (or whatever).

Comment: I can reproduce the problem every time by accidently adding a line of code: DWORD Function(DWORD input); into VS (i.e. defining a function within a function) and then putting a breakpoint on it. VS compiles it without error, but the breakpoint will move when debugging. I guess because it's an unused function it skips over it. Still sh*tty VS behaviour though - I would have expected VS to just not compile it.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the file containing that code doesn't have any optimization flags that override the global settings.

Comment: This is most likely whats happening. Optimizations can reorder the execution of your code, which can make setting useful breakpoints hard. When that happens to me, I generally either recompile without optimizations or drop down into assembly code to see what's really happening (it's not as bad as you might think :) )

Answer (score 4):

I found end-of-line could cause the problem like this. Once I changed some lines from the windows style carriage to linux style carriage by accident, the debugging point no longer hit the line. What I did to solve the problem was using notepad++ to fix EOL

Comment: I guess you meant "end-of-line". I just faced this problem and fixed it as you have described.

Comment: I just ran into the very same issue, the encoding wasn't ANSI and that seemingly messed up the breakpoints.

Answer (score 3):

When I see things like this the first thing i always do is to open up the Debug->Modules window and make sure that the binary I'm debugging was loaded from the place I think it should be.

Comment: first reaction also, but he says "Checked that the debug path is the same as the build output path." so I think it is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas:

1. Your source file has been changed
   since you last ran the debugger.
2. Your code has been optimized and
   perhaps some lines removed by the
   compiler through optimization.
3. VS doesn't like the actually line
   the breakpoint is assigned to.  It
   always likes the the last line of a
   statement spread across several
   lines.
4. The source file your displaying is
   different than the source file that
   was compiled (they could be from two
   different folders).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and worked around it by creating a new "solution" in VS and importing the existing .h and .cpp files into it.

Debugging problems gone.

I'm sure the issue was somewhere in the config settings.