# Unable to hit the proper Debug point in the code for VS2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

So I am actually trying to debug an ASP.NET MVC project that I am opening as a website. I have placed the breakpoint at a particular controller Action method but on running the project and navigating to the breakpoint, the breakpoint shifts five lines further and then sometimes it doesn't even continue to debug and abruptly returns back to the web-page.

Keep in mind I have made and tested several changes to the debugger settings from the support available online. This is a major bottleneck for our production coding. Thanks in advance for any piece of advice.

Comment: This sort of problem can often be fixed by cleaning your solution, and manually removing everything from obj and bin folders if cleaning the project leaves stuff there.

Comment: Also make sure that you're building in Debug mode to avoid having the compiler optimize away parts of your code. And [some](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45886261/120955) [people](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14466162/120955) have found that inconsistent line endings in their files cause this kind of behavior.

Comment: You'd better provide more information (screenshots) to explain what is "I am actually trying to debug an ASP.NET MVC project that I am opening as a website". Most people open the project directly in VS and start debugging, so that VS knows how to attach the debugger and locate the symbol files (so that break points can work). If you don't go that typical ways, the debugger might not even attach, or the symbols cannot be found.